# Copy objects into a list in Python

Tags: python

I would like to get values from an ODBC source with pyodbc. The `fetchall` method returns a list of `pyodbc.Row`. This list have missing entries so I would like to create a new list with default values for the missing entries.

Here an example:

```
data = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM BuildingA").fetchall()
```

Data contains:

```
{floor: 2,  company: 'foo'}, 
{floor: 42, company: 'bar'},
```

The building have 50 floors, I want a list that contains 50 floors with default values:

```
class emptyFloor:
    company = 'none'

building = list()
for i in range(50):
    building.append(emptyFloor)

for item in data:
    building[item.floor] = item
```

Unfortunately this last line doesn't work because I cannot use this to fetch the company on the floor 42:

```
buidling[42].company
```

The type of item is `<type 'pyodbc.Row'>` and the type of `building[42]` is `<type 'classobj'>`. How can I save the `item` object into my list?

**EDIT**

Actually it would be much better to fill the complete list with all the columns found in the database and with `undef` or `null` values. I found this solution which doesn't answer the main question:

```
emptyFloor = {}
for row in cursor.columns(table=table):
    emptyFloor[row.column_name] = None

building = list();
for i in range(50):
    building.append(emptyFloor)

for item in data:
    it = {}
    for row in cursor.columns(table=table):
        it[row.column_name] = item.__getattribute__(row.column_name)
    building[item.Index] = it
```

I feel this is very ugly. Any better suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: what is this `mon` variable you use in the first loop?

Comment: After you do `cursor.execute`, don't you need to run `cursor.fetchall()`?

Comment: Do you really need the class emptyFloor?  and maybe you can do something like str(item.company)

Comment: so, the data is returned as a dictionary right? You might want to look into the `collections.defaultdict` type

Comment: @Rodin my mistake... I made a correction

Comment: @mu無 the fetchall is at the end of the line `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM BuildingA").fetchall()`

Comment: @Rodin I don't know what `pyodbc.Row` inherit  from